# Change control property located in Window.Resources from code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, controltemplate

I have a WPF window with custom style like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" Width="525" Style="{DynamicResource CustomWindowStyle}">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CustomWindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="7" Background="{x:Null}" MouseMove="WindowMouseMove" MouseDown="WindowMouseDown">
                            <Grid Background="Transparent" DockPanel.Dock="Top">

                            <!--WPF Control of interest-->
                            <Border x:Name="BORDERCONTROL" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Width="20" Height="20" Background="Black" />
                            <AdornerDecorator>
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                        </AdornerDecorator>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>

</Grid>
```

I want to change BORDERCONTROL background programmatically like this:

```
private void ChangeBackground()
{
     BORDERCONTROL.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
}
```

But I can't get access to this control using this method.

Is there a simple way to change control property located in control template from code-behind?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Border b = (Border)this.Template.FindName("BORDERCONTROL", this);
        b.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
    }
```

This will give you the desired Border control, and change its color. But don't try to access the Border in the Window Constructor, as it will always be null.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var bor = (Border)Template.FindName("BORDERCONTROL", this);
bor.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `TemplateBinding` you can bind to the Window's `Background` property and change that:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomWindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="7" Background="{x:Null}" 
                            MouseMove="WindowMouseMove" MouseDown="WindowMouseDown">
                            <Grid Background="Transparent" DockPanel.Dock="Top">

                            <!--WPF Control of interest-->
                            <Border x:Name="BORDERCONTROL" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                    Margin="10,10,0,0" Width="20" Height="20" 
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                            <AdornerDecorator>
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                        </AdornerDecorator>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

private void ChangeBackground()
{
     myWindow.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying help. I think that the @AnjumSKhan solution is better for me.